# Whatsapp usage with old lost number

Tags: samsung, ios

I lost my android phone (samsung galaxy grand) . Can I use whatsapp with the same number on my new phone, if I don't have the sim card with that number ? Except for the sms code/call, is there some other method of opening my whatsapp account ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible. If I were you, I would send a broadcast message to all of my contacts regarding my new number.

Answer (score 0):

you could ask your carrier to disable your old sim card and enable a new one (which you need to get) with the same number.